# Trying to simplify style in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I currently have a datagrid with a bunch of columns. All of the columns have the following style

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Instead of repeating this within each DataGridTextColumn how could I assign this to all the columns in a more simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the DataGridCell and DataGridColumnHeader styles, then just set that style on the DataGrid style.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="StyledCells">
    <!-- Setter Details -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="StyledColumnHeader">
    <!-- Setter Details -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource StyledColumnHeader}" />
    <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource StyledCells}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work at all. How would you apply my styles in this case? Edit: got it to work by applying BasedOn propertyies!

Comment: Im trying to have a single column have a different style now. How would I go about doing that, again i'd like to do it using a resource.

Comment: Define a separate DataGridCell style and set the CellStyle for the DataGridTextColumn as the different style. That would effectively override the styling for that column.